# Get directory-specific Nautilus preferences on 14.04 LTS

Tags: nautilus, preferences

Unsure how to word this, but is there anyway for Ubuntu to display certain folders, certain ways.

I have alot of holiday/family shots, in a large number of folders named after where they from. So when browsing through the main folder I like the list view so I can easily just scroll down looking at the names. However when I open the folder which has only images in, is there anyway for it to automatically change to a large grid format?

So basically is there a way for me to add a preference, to a folder with certain files within?

I have done some searches, but I can't seem to find anything like this.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary: it is not possible with the standard file manager, I cannot find out if by design or because of a bug.

The KDE file manager "dolphin" do what you need, but does not blend so well with standard Unity/Gnome appearance. You can install it via `sudo apt-get install dolphin`, but be warned, it will install **a lot** of KDE things. (And it has its drawbacks, too, like the fact that the thumbnails are in my opinion managed much better in `nautilus`).

[image: Dolphin showup]

TL,DR version:

Once upon a time, `nautilus` (the file manager used in Gnome and Unity) used to remember the view mode for each directory. Then the "simplification frenzy" started, and willing or not, a lot of nice features were deemed "too complex" and ditched. Emblems, tree view, double pane, and this thing you are asking for. Although maybe this one was just a bug, I am not sure --- see https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=683802.

Linux used to have the best graphical file managers around; now probably (apart from KDE `dolphin` and maybe `nemo`) I sometime wish to have the windows file manager available.

Comment: Thanks for the response. From the Bugzilla link, seems like from the time for the first post to now, that it wont be fixed, damn shame. I'll look into KDE, shame to mess up the look of Ubuntu but I'd rather have less headaches and clicking. Again, thanks.

Comment: It may be worth a shot to try `nemo` or `thunar` from the repos. I think they're less of a jump than going to KDE/dolphin.

Comment: `thunar` do the same as `nautilus` with respect of view mode of the directory, unfortunately. I did not check `nemo`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a fix...

Open a window.
Don't click on anything.

With the browser window as the active window, "Mouse" to the upper left-hand corner of the screen.

Click Edit > Preferences.
Under the "Views" tab, change your default view to what you want. 
- Also, change the zoom level of "List View" to 50%.